# Make Cursor position in center for ui.helper in jquery-ui draggable method

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I want **cursor** to be in **center** for **ui.helper of draggable** .

I am doing this like this

```
$(".soclass").draggable({

          cursor: "move",
          helper: 'clone',
          revert: "invalid",
          tolerance: "fit",
          start: function(event, ui){

             $(this).draggable("option", "cursorAt", {
            left: Math.floor(ui.helper.width() / 2),
            top: Math.floor(ui.helper.height() / 2)
          }); 


          }

      });
```

> Using this *i get cursor in the center only after First drop*.
>   **How can I center align the cursor right from first drop.**

[**Jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/8fc76rte/)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can access the **offset.click** property of the draggable instance, which is pretty much what setting the cursor at option does The problem with setting the option, is that as you describe it'll be applied only next time you trigger the **start** event. But using the property you can set it on the current event. Like this:

```
start: function(event, ui){
    $(this).draggable('instance').offset.click = {
        left: Math.floor(ui.helper.width() / 2),
        top: Math.floor(ui.helper.height() / 2)
    }; 
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/38fay00b/

Comment: Yea thanks that worked ,,, Can you please explain the instance concept

Comment: Instance is a method that gives access to the data of a specific draggable. When you assign draggable, it in fact creates a draggable object that takes care of all the behaviors and callback. All the methods and properties available such as start, cursorAt and more are part of that object.

Comment: Works like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

I create this solution and this only works for me

```
$('.soclass').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).draggable("option", "cursorAt", {top: 0, left: $(this).width()/2 });
});
```

Comment: This worked for me, I assume people downvoted because your explanation sounds like you're saying it won't work for others.